# Is there any way to annotate google street view?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-street-view

I'd like to annotation google street view with Maps v3 .

Here is an Maps v2 plugin library can do that :

http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.com/2009/11/mapsicle-10-annotating-street-view.html

But my application is under Maps v3 , I wonder whether Maps v3 has added this feather by default.

Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The InfoWindow could be used for Street View:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#InfoWindows